# How can I select data from multiple tables?

Tags: linq

In my MVC project, I have some tables like this:

- Form (`FormID, SectionID`)
- Section (`SectionID, SectionName`)
- SectionQuestion (`SectionID, QuestionID`)
- Question `(QuestionID, Content`)

A form has multiple sections, and a section has some questions.

I can get all question for the `FormID`. But I want to get a list of sections (which contain questions) for the model.

It means in the view I want to do something like this:

```
@Model IEnumerable<MedialForm.Models.Sections>

foreach (var section in Model)
{
     //Show questions
}
```

Can you guys help me? :)

Comment: Do you use linq-to-sql or entity framework? If you use ef, what type of ef do you use? Code first, db first or model first?

Comment: Hi, I use Model. Get Form:
var forms = Form.Objects.Where(x => x.FormID == id);

Comment: What ORM (object-relation mapping) do you use to map your database to your classes Form, Section, etc?

Comment: This question is so basic that I think you should first get up to date with how to work with EF (never mind, we all started one day). Highly recommended is Julie Lerman's book _DbContext_. Your question is about navigation properties and/or `join` and/or `Include`, but there is more to say about how to use these in a sensible way.

Answer (score 0):

You will not see a list of sections for a form, since the Form can only have 1 section. (i.e. the SectionID is defined in Form, and not FormID in Section). However the following Linq query will return the section and the associated questions for a specified FormID:

```
void Main()
{
    var sections = 
        new [] 
        {
            new Section { SectionID = 1, SectionName = "SectionName1" },
            new Section { SectionID = 2, SectionName = "SectionName2" }
        };

    var forms = 
        new []
        {
            new Form { FormID = 1, SectionID = 1 },
            new Form { FormID = 2, SectionID = 1 },
            new Form { FormID = 3, SectionID = 2 },
            new Form { FormID = 4, SectionID = 2 }
        };

    var questions =
        new[]
        {
            new Question { QuestionID = 1, Content = "Question1" },
            new Question { QuestionID = 2, Content = "Question2" }
        };

    var sectionQuestions =
        new[]
        {
            new SectionQuestion { SectionID = 1, QuestionID = 1 },
            new SectionQuestion { SectionID = 2, QuestionID = 1 },
            new SectionQuestion { SectionID = 2, QuestionID = 2 }
        };

    var formId = 4;

    var result = forms
        .Join(
            sections, 
            f => f.SectionID, 
            s => s.SectionID, 
            (f, s) => new { Form = f, Section = s })
        .Join(
            sectionQuestions, 
            jfs => jfs.Section.SectionID, 
            sq => sq.SectionID, 
            (jfs, sq) => new { Form = jfs.Form, Section = jfs.Section, sq.QuestionID })
        .Join(
            questions, 
            jfsq => jfsq.QuestionID, 
            q => q.QuestionID, 
            (jfsq, q) => new { Form = jfsq.Form, Section = jfsq.Section, Question = q })
        .Where(f => f.Form.FormID == formId)
        .GroupBy(f => f.Section.SectionID)
        .Select(grp => new { SectionID = grp.Key, Questions = grp.Select(g => g.Question)});

    Console.WriteLine($"For Form: {formId} the following sections with their questions were found: {String.Join(", ", result.Select(r => $"SectionID: {r.SectionID}, QuestionIDs: [{String.Join(", ", r.Questions.Select(q => q.QuestionID))}]"))}");
}

public class Form
{
    public Int32 FormID { get; set; }
    public Int32 SectionID { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public Int32 SectionID { get; set; }
    public String SectionName { get; set; }
}

public class SectionQuestion
{
    public Int32 SectionID { get; set; }
    public Int32 QuestionID { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public Int32 QuestionID { get; set; }
    public String Content { get; set; }
}
```

This will return the following result:

> For Form: 4 the following sections with their questions were found: SectionID: 2, QuestionIDs: [1, 2]